# Request guidance on error in receiving token in Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-passport

**Greetings and Regards**

I am designing an api with Laravel and using a passport for an app.

I'm having trouble logging in using the login endpoint.

**The problem I encountered is as follows:**

[image]

I will send the necessary parameters to the server including

```
client_id - grant_type - username - password - client_secret - scope:
{{server_url}}/api / v1 / login
```

**In the login method:**

After evaluating entries I send a request to oauth/token to receive theta token.
I get the error below.

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST
>   http://divar.local/oauth/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`
>   response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided
>   authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner
>   (truncated...)

**The contents of the login method**

```
public function login()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'mobile_number' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $response['errors'] = $validator->errors();
            return response()->json($response, 401);
        }
        $clientOauthData = Client::where('password_client', 1)->where('name', 'Laravel Password Grant Client')->first();
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $response = $http->post(env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => $clientOauthData->id,
                'client_secret' => $clientOauthData->secret,
                'username' => request('mobile_number'),
                'password' => request('password'),
                'scope' => '',
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json'
            ]
        ]);

        $response = json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
```

Request headers :
[image]
Request body :
[image]

Comment: from the Postman panel, choose "preview" button to see the problem. Or you can send the header->Accept:application/json to get errors in json. then post the errors here. adding a screenshot of request headers and body helps tooo

Comment: @FatemehMajd Thanks for your accountability
I added at the end of the question

Comment: try using "password" instead of password in grant type. Postman sometimes has problems with strings. add quotes

Comment: @FatemehMajd  I tried, the problem is also there

Comment: have you enabled password grant for the client?

Comment: Where can I activate?
The value password_client inside the table oauth_clients is 1

Comment: that's the one. Then I'm almost clueless in this situation. I recommend going to the file which throws the exception and dumping both available grants and the requested grant to see if there is any difference, or if the password grant is even enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I always proceed this request.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|mobile_phone',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

   $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

   try {
    $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 'your client ID',
            'client_secret' => 'secret ID,
            'username' => $request->mobile_phone,
            'password' => $request->password,
            // 'scope' => '',
        ],
    ]);

    return $response->getBody();

    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 401) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'This action can\'t be perfomed at this time. Please try later.'], $e->getCode());
        } else if ($e->getCode() == 400) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.'], $e->getCode());
        }

        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server. Please try letar.', $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your accountability
I also tried this method and gave another error:
`"message": "cURL error 3:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)",
    "exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException",
    "file": "F:\\dev\\workspace\\laravel\\divar\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
    "line": 201,`

Comment: Try to install Guzzle.  `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`.  Then if the issue persist, try to import these classes:  `use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;`

Comment: they have guzzle and are using guzzle

Comment: {
    "message": "These credentials do not match our records."
}

Comment: Which means that the request is reaching the serve side. Please make sure the form_params in your login method is set correctly(check the client_id and secret_id). In Postman just use username and password. If you'are using mobile_number and password to login, make sure you call the mobile_number field and password field from user table

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.
My application scenario is that the user sends a roust to the server.
This recipe contains a mobile number and so on.
My system authentication is a one-time password.
The user should receive it via SMS and then receive Token.
In this recipe I want to generate a password and create a token and send it to the user with the activation code.
Where's the problem with my scenario?

Comment: Then it will become a different topic. Your question sounded like a regular api auth. For what you are asking now it becomes more complex. It will require a clear explanation how you are trying to achieve and we can help you from there.  Please upvote/accept my answer if it solved the original question. Thanks.